# Program to determine if 3 sides form a valid triangle using Java

Tags: java, methods, boolean

Given three integers a, b, and c, return true if a, b, and c could be the lengths of the sides of a right triangle. Return false otherwise. Recall that in a right triangle, each side must have a positive length, and the sum of the squares of the leg lengths must equal the square of the length of the hypotenuse.

isRightTriangle(3, 4, 5) → true
isRightTriangle(4, 3, 5) → true
isRightTriangle(5, 4, 3) → true

```
boolean isRightTriangle(int a, int b, int c) {
  if(a>0 && b>0 && c>0){
    if((Math.sqrt((double)a)+Math.sqrt((double)b))==Math.sqrt((double)c)){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      if((Math.sqrt((double)b)+Math.sqrt((double)c))==Math.sqrt((double)a)){
        return true;
      }
      else{
        if((Math.sqrt(c)+Math.sqrt(b))==Math.sqrt(a)){
          return true;
        }
        else{
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your title says "valid triangle" but your question text says "right triangle".  These are two different things.  Can you please either change the title or the question text, so that they're both the same?

Comment: But the problem with your code is that you're taking square roots instead of squaring.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Math.sqrt instead of Math.pow(x, 2). You need to check that a^2+b^2=c^2, not sqrt(a)+sqrt(b)=sqrt(c).

```
boolean isRightTriangle(int a, int b, int c) {
  // lets exit if variables are bad
  if(a < 1 || b < 1 || c < 1) {
    return false;
  }
  // lets create an array so we can sort
  int[] arry = new int[3];
  arry[0] = a;
  arry[1] = b;
  arry[2] = c;
  Arrays.sort(arry);
  // now that the array is sorted, the largest number (the hypotenuse) should be arry[2]
  return Math.pow(arry[0], 2) + Math.pow(arry[1], 2) == Math.pow(arry[2], 2);
}
```